# How to Set Local Android Calendar Event to Going=true so it syncs w/Google Calendar (using Titanium)

Tags: android, calendar, titanium, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

Using Titanium, it is easy to add events to a local Android calendar.

But it seems that unless the user opens the added event and clicks "Yes" next to Going? the item will not sync with the online calendar.

Is there a way to programatically set Going? to Yes so the item will sync?

I've done extensive searches and can't find anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "local Android calendar"? Is this something intrinsic to Titanium?

Comment: By local Android calendar, I mean the calendar that saves and reads to local storage on the device, as opposed to the remote Google Calendar entries that most Android devices sync with. This is intrinsic to Android, not Titanium.